# Eigenvalues of a resriction of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, projection, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space, let $A$ be a compact operator on $H$ whose spectrum does not contain $1$, i.e., $1-A$ is invertible, and let $P$ be an orthogonal projection on some proper subspace $S$ of $H$. Then is it possible for $PAP$ to have $1$ as one of its eigenvalues?

Comment: I cannot understand why somebody thinks this question should be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this can happen even in finite dimension. Let $H=\mathbb C^2$ and
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $2$. Meanwhile, if you consider
$P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, the eigenvalues of
$$
PAP=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$ are $0$ and $1$.